# Travsering table and storing values as key/value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table like

```
  <table>
    <tbody><tr><th>Course Name</th>
    <th>Course ID</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    </tr><tr>
<td>Course A</td>  
<td class="asset-id">1616781</td>  
<td class="asset-val">1306886</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Course B</td>  
<td class="asset-id">723507</td>  
<td class="asset-val">1306886</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Course C</td>  
<td class="asset-id">723503</td>  
<td class="asset-val">1306886</td>
</tr>
```

I want to traverse this table and create an Array of objects like

```
[{
    "id": 1616781,
    "value": 1306886
}, {
    "id": 723507,
    "value": 1306886
}, {
    "id": 723503,
    "value": 1306886
}]
```

I have tried something like this so far, but its not working ...

```
 var myArray = [];
 $('.asset-id, .asset-val').each(function(i, obj) {                
            var tmpObj = {};
            var asset_key='';
            var asset_text='';

            tmpObj[asset_key] = $(".asset-id", this).text();
            tmpObj[asset_text] = $(".asset-val", this).text();
            myArray.push(tmpObj)
            console.log(myArray);

        });
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a few problems with your code:

1. `myArray` is defined inside the loop, so you're always instantiating it with an empty array.
2. The selectors don't work because you're looping over each element.
3. Both `asset_key` and `asset_text` are empty strings.

Te following should work for you:

```js
var arr = [ ];

$('.asset-id').each(function() {
  arr.push({ 
    'id': $(this).text(),
    'value': $(this).siblings(".asset-val").text()
  });
}); 

console.log( arr );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Course Name</th>
    <th>Course ID</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Course A</td>  
    <td class="asset-id">1616781</td>  
    <td class="asset-val">1306886</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Course B</td>  
    <td class="asset-id">723507</td>  
    <td class="asset-val">1306886</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Course C</td>  
    <td class="asset-id">723503</td>  
    <td class="asset-val">1306886</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @BenM, Actually `myArray` was defined outside, I made mistake while copying the code here. Fixed now. Anyway, Thanks for your help, your code works and its very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over the rows and finding each td, you can just select all the elements and loop over that.

```js
var ids = $('.asset-id')
var vals = $('.asset-val')

var result = [];
ids.each(function(i, v){
  result.push({ id: +v.textContent, value: +vals.eq(i).text()})
  // result.push({ id: +ids.eq(i).text(), value: +vals.eq(i).text()})
  
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Course Name</th>
      <th>Course ID</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Course A</td>
      <td class="asset-id">1616781</td>
      <td class="asset-val">1306886</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Course B</td>
      <td class="asset-id">723507</td>
      <td class="asset-val">1306886</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Course C</td>
      <td class="asset-id">723503</td>
      <td class="asset-val">1306886</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```